# Не работает форма логина

Tags: php, mysqli

Ситуация такая. Есть форма логина, при входе из таблицы берётся массив данных, в котором сравниваются логин и пароль. Однако это не срабатывает. Есть два варианта: первый — когда пароль в принципе бесполезен, то есть, ввести вместо пароля можно что угодно, и он работает. Второй — это когда не пускает даже при вводе верного пароля. Вот код, подскажите, что не так!

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['login'])) 
    { $login = $_POST['login']; 
    if ($login == '') { unset($login);} 
}

if (isset($_POST['pass'])) 
    { $password=$_POST['pass']; 
    if ($password =='') { unset($password);} 
}

if (empty($login) || empty($password)) 
    {
    exit ("Неправильный логин или пароль!<a href='../login.php'>Ввести еще раз!</a>");
    }

$login = stripslashes($login);
$login = htmlspecialchars($login);

$password = stripslashes($password);
$password = htmlspecialchars($password);

$login = trim($login);
$password = trim($password);

$password = sha1($password);

include "db_connect.php";

$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$login'");
$myrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if (empty($myrow)) {
    exit ("Неправильный логин или пароль!<a href='../login.php'>Ввести еще раз!!</a>");
}else{
    if ($myrow['password']==$password){
        $_SESSION['login']=$myrow['login'];
        $_SESSION['name']=$myrow['name']; 
        $_SESSION['mail']=$myrow['mail'];
        $_SESSION['second_name']=$myrow['second_name']; 
        $_SESSION['id']=$myrow['id'];
        echo "Вы успешно вошли в личный кабинет! <a href='../lichniy_kabinet.php'>Перейти</a>";
    }else{
        exit ("Неправильный логин или пароль!<a href='../login.php'>Ввести еще раз!</a>");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Больше подробностей, пожалуйста. Как оно "не срабатывает"? Какие-то ошибки? Непредвиденное поведение?

Comment: Никаких ошибок не выдает. В первом случае, когда в строке "if ($myrow['password']==$password){" стоит знак присваивания, то тогда об как бы срабатывает только по логину, то есть пароль можно любой ввести и он прокатит, а если в этой же строке стоит оператор сравнивания, как сейчас, то пароль не срабатывает, даже если он правильный.

Comment: А какой вообще смысл использовать оператор присваивания в условии, не совсем понял.

Comment: Я просто тестил, и заметил такую вещь. По этому и описал. Я понимаю что нужен оператор сравнения. С ним не проходит логинизация и именно с 'password'. Проверил с 'login' и всё работает.

Comment: То есть вы хотите сказать, что код не обнаруживает "пустость" пароля?

Comment: но он не пустой. в переменную $password прилетает значение через POST, затем, оно шифруется и сравнивается со значением взятым из бд, но я что то делаю не так и хочу что бы мне указали на мою ошибку, потому как я тупо не вижу ее

Comment: По описанию вероятнее всего то, что вы неправильно шифруете. При записи в БД используется один шифр, а при сравнении пароль шифруется по-другому. Сравните локально: возьмите хеш пароля из БД, зашифруйте вручную пароль, который вводите и сравните получаемые значения.

Comment: не, с шифровкой всё нормально, шифрую sha1. и при регистрации и при логине

Comment: Еще раз говорю: сравните локально 2 значения. Вполне вероятно, что функции типа trim урезают какие-то символы в пароле при входе, а при регистрации эта функция не используется, соответственно вы получаете 2 абсолютно разных хеша. P.S. sha1 для пароля? Я использовать md5, обернутый в sha-512 с солью в свое время и все еще беспокоился о безопасности. Либо я параноик, либо вы слишком безолаберный.

Comment: без шифровок, всё работает нормально, с шифровкой (sha1 или md5) не работает

Comment: скорее и то и то)))

Comment: Значит дело 100% в шифровании, если без него все нормально.

Comment: Понял, спасибо) от этого и оттолкнусь

Comment: Обращайтесь :))

Answer (score 1):

Незнаю в чем именно у Вас, беда может с базой не соеденяется, может еще что, но вот вам рабочий код для Вашего случая. Проверьте выборку на количество элементов, если больше 0 то значит в базе есть такой пользователь с таким паролем. П.С используйте плейсхолдеры.

```
<?php
session_start();
$er = False;
if (empty($_POST['login']) || empty($_POST['pass'])) exit ("Неправильный логин или пароль!<a href='../login.php'>Ввести еще раз!</a>");
// include "db_connect.php";
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
///////////////////////////
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = ? and password = ?"))
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['login'], sha1($_POST['pass'])); 
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую такой вариант!)